# Opposite of group concat and average one column based on number of ID's

Tags: mysql

My table looks like

```
ID        Name      Revenue
A1|A2     ABC       4
A3|A2|A1  XYZ.      9
A1.       IJK.      2
A1|A3.    DEF.      1
```

My output should be

```
ID  Name  Revenue
A1. ABC  2
A2. ABC  2
A3. XYZ  3
A2. XYZ  3
A1. XYZ  3
A1. IJK  2
A1. DEF  0.5
A3. DEF  0.5
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: I linked this to a duplicate question from 2013. The complexity of those solutions should serve as a caution against storing data this way, if you want to use it as if it is stored in multiple rows. Just store it in a normalized manner, and make it easier on yourself!

Comment: But this link does not provide how to calculate the average after breaking the ID's. This question is actually not the duplicate of the link you mentioned.

Comment: Then store the data in a normal format, so you can solve the query.